# Checking for each value in Hashset when querying

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a query where in the WHERE statement, I check for values where a hashset contains a column, i.e.:

```
var cHashset = {"cat","dog","bird"}
```

Database looks like:

```
ID    Category
1     dog
1     cat
1     bird
2     dog
3     cat
3     dog
4     bird
```

Then for the Where section of the query I have:

```
.Where(o => cHashset.Contains(o.Category))
.Select (o => o.ID).Distinct();
```

How can I make sure I only select values where they have categories of cat, dog AND bird?  The current setup above works fine if it is only looking for one category but not if I need to assure all categories.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: So you want all those IDs where all three categories are present (`1` in your example if I´m right)?

Comment: Correct. @HimBromBeere

Answer (score 1):

You have to group by your id first. Now you can look if all the elements from your `cHashSet` are contained in the categories of the given group.

```
var result = myData.GroupBy(x => x.ID)
    .Where(x => cHashSet.All(y => x.Select(z => z.Category).Contains(y)))
    .Select(x => x.ID);
```

Comment: You missed closing one extension `.Where(` I think.